# Why does my log in persist after a database reset and seed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-cookies, railstutorial.org

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial ([railstutorial.org](http://railstutorial.org)). I've completed the tutorial up to and including chapter nine, and after resetting and reseeding the database, and restarting the server I find I am still logged into the site.

The user I had been logged in as previously was deleted in the reset, and had a unique password. When I visited the profile view and edit pages I was shown the pages of the seeded user with the same user id as my now deleted user. I'm able to reset the password of the seeded user.

If you're unfamiliar, I the tutorial uses rail's session method for temporary sessions and creates it's own sessions controller to do a persistent log in.

I checked the cookies in my browser against the new development database, and while I see the Seeded user I had logged in as there, I don't see any correspondence between the database entries and my cookies.

I've gone back and compared the sessions chapter and what I have in the tests and controller, nothing has jumped out at me. I'm a complete novice, and this is really throwing me for a loop. Does it sound like I fudged something critical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting your server doesn't clear the session.

And the browser still has a cookie, which is an id for a session.
The browser sends the request, including the cookie. The server looks up the session by the id and finds a hash, which most likely identifies the user by their id.

It does not store any password information; that is only for creating the session. Since the user after reset has the same id, Rails doesn't know that it's actually a different user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What would clear the session? Is there a place where I can view the stored session information? Am I asking too many questions?

Comment: You can clear the session by assigning `session[:user_id] = nil` if you are using session[:user_id] to store the session. Look at the code in sessions_controller#create to see how it is stored.